# Mod Rewrite for this condition

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im trying to rewrite 
*www.mysite.com/admin/index.php?page=pagename* to *www.mysite.com/admin/pagename*

In my .htaccess file (located in www.mysite.com/admin) is the following lines of code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

However, when I try to access

```
www.mysite.com/admin/mypage?querystring=value
```

I have to type

```
 www.mysite.com/admin/mypage&querystring=value
```

instead.  The first ? must be an & sign because of the mod rewrite.

How can I make a rewrite rule that will fix this problem.  So I want

```
www.mysite.com/admin/mypage/?additional_query=value
```

to rewrite to

```
www.mysite.com/admin/index.php?page=mypage&aditional_query=value
```

I think google uses the # sign or something, or places a / afterwards.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache already has a neat little modifier that you can add to the end of your RewriteRule. If you just change your flag (`[L]`) at the end of your rule to `[QSA,L]` it will append your query string to the end of the URL, rather than trying to rewrite the page with it still included (as long as the query string starts with the `?` as expected.

I'm not sure, but I believe you need to remove the `$` symbol as well.

**New line:**

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/? index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that made no difference. :(